# What attack can generate the most Sepith Fragments with Sepith Up?

Tags: legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky

I've noticed in *The Legend of Heroes: Trails in the Sky* that when i have the Sepith Up Turn Bonus some attacks like Estelle's Pummel S-Break will cause more Sepith Fragments to fall in an attack despite only dealing damage once as opposed to if she just did a regular attack.

I figured this is because Estelle's Pummel has more "hits" to the attack compared to Joshua's Sever. so i am wondering which attack can generate the most Sepith Fragments with Sepith UP?